# What are the missing features in adempiere web UI

Tags: erp, adempiere, webui

I was working on the ADempiere Web UI. But found many features are not working in Web UI like `value format` . And found some forms are not working properly. Can you list out the mis links in WEBUI compare to the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important things are

1.Reset user password does not submit changes

2.Cannot create a new Sales Order. If created, cannot be saved. DocType and Partner Locations Fields doesn't retrieve anything.

3.When creating a line item, if product is updated to choose one different from the originally chosen, the unit price and line amount are not updated unless the quantity is changed.

4.When trying to create a PO from a requisition, the process fails with an error without any further description of the problem

5.Some pull down selection such as for categories and codes doesn't work. They have zoom buttons but some have no window error. The common error is eve though it has a window when zoomed, it doesnt do anything to get the selected value back.

6.Cannot Open/Close Periods, Period Action doesnt have values.

Comment: whatever you have mentioned all points functional aspect not UI related.

Comment: You mentioned above all are working properly in adempiere 360/370 versions.